# Do docker images with different tags weigh the same separately?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have been doing deployments for some projects for quite a few weeks, therefore I have several images for the same repository with different tags
I have been doing deployments for some projects for quite a few weeks, therefore I have several images for the same repository with different tags.
So with `docker images` I get things like this on my local:

[image]

I delete some image from a tag, but I don't free up 330 MB of storage. So doesn't each of these images weigh 330 MB separately?

I had understood that docker with its layer system would simply put layers on top of others if necessary, but this log has me a little confused.

Comment: just the answer I was hoping for

Comment: Questions asking "what would happen if I do X?" don't work well on the site. You are in the best position to run the command and inspect the result. If the result is unexpected, create a [mcve] for others to test locally, along with the commands run and their output.

Comment: Ok, I agree that I skipped the step of testing and stating that the space had not been freed. My question is poorly formulated. Why didn't you make the second comment from the beginning? We are here to help each other

Comment: In any case, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size listing is a simple sum of all of the layers for an image. There's no easy/good way to accurately list the unique layer size of the image in a way that would make everyone happy. Since there will frequently be a number of layers in common between images, trying to sum the size of multiple images will often double count those shared layers.

The other images on the machine can change over time, which would mean a unique size would change as other images are added and deleted, require expensive recalcuations with every build/push/pull/delete. And not including the size of the shared layers in the listing would mean some layer usage would be unlisted until all common images are deleted. And users tend to want to know how much space an image is using even if there are common layers since that indicates an upper limit on space that will be needed if the image is pushed/pulled to another machine.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. Your response has been very helpful to me.